# Best way to add enemy and pawn to the stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class

Im trying to develop simple pawn (player) and enemy classes but there is 2 story and each have their problems.

first: when the pawn and enemies are added to stage by code in the document class I have the advantage to use them by instance name I used to add them for things like hit test (I guess)

second: when I add them to the stage by dragging them from library to stage. this way I can add event listeners to the stage inside them (for movements) but accessing them gets hard and sometimes the null stage is my biggest problem.

any suggestion to make things easy?

for example In the pawn class below I added keyboard listener to the stage but when I add this pawn to the stage by add child I get access to null ... error

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

public class pwn extends MovieClip {
    public var upPressed:Boolean = false;
    public var downPressed:Boolean = false;
    public var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
    public var rightPressed:Boolean = false;
    public var lastMove:String;
    public static var spd:Number=6;



    public function pwn() {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_SetKeyPressed);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, fl_UnsetKeyPressed);


    }
    //Movement
    public function fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey(event:Event){
        if (leftPressed){
            x -= spd;
            if(currentFrame < 18 || currentFrame > 24){
                gotoAndPlay(17);
            }
        }else
        if (rightPressed){
            x += spd;
            if(currentFrame < 26 || currentFrame > 31){
                gotoAndPlay(25);
            }
        }else
        if (upPressed){
            y -= spd;
            if(currentFrame < 10 || currentFrame > 16){
                gotoAndPlay(9);
            }
        }else
        if (downPressed){
            y += spd;
            if(currentFrame < 2 || currentFrame > 8){
                gotoAndPlay(1);
            }
        }
    }
    public function fl_SetKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
        switch (event.keyCode){
            case 87:
            case 38:{
                upPressed = true;
                break;
            }
            case 83:
            case 40:{
                downPressed = true;
                break;
            }
            case 65:
            case 37:{
                leftPressed = true;
                break;
            }
            case 68:
            case 39:{
                rightPressed = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    public function fl_UnsetKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
        switch (event.keyCode){
            case 87:
            case 38:{
                upPressed = false;
                break;
            }
            case 83:
            case 40:{
                downPressed = false;
                break;
            }
            case 65:
            case 37:{
                leftPressed = false;
                break;
            }
            case 68:
            case 39:{
                rightPressed = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

what do you in these situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions to this problem. First let me explain that when you create a new display object and it hasn't been added to the stage or any object in the display list its reference to the stage is null. So one way to do this is pass a reference to the stage in the pawn class constructor:

```
public function pwn(stageRef:Stage) {
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey);
    stageRef.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_SetKeyPressed);
    stageRef.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, fl_UnsetKeyPressed);
}
```

The second way is to use the ADDED_TO_STAGE event:

```
public function pwn() {
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey);
    this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
}

private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void {
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_SetKeyPressed);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, fl_UnsetKeyPressed);
}
```

Comment: coooool now I have some answer to my eternal question since I started using classes. thank you.

// any additional advise over using addChild vs dragging from library to the stage?

Comment: Well I'm not certain what you mean by dragging them from the library to stage ( assuming you mean you are taking them from the library in the IDE and placing them on the stage? ). But there are many options for getting an asset ( movieclip, graphic, etc ) from your library to the stage or any parent display object. You can adjust the properties of object in the library to "Export for ActionScript" and give it a class name, then you can do addChild( new "insertClassName"() ). Another option is to export the assets as a SWF or a SWC and access them that way. I would do a little googling for that

Comment: I didn't know there is more ways. lots to learn about this class thing ^_^. 
now I imported 2 objects by addClid in my document class and added a new function to my pwn class to detect collision wondering how to pass the other object "var s1:Symbol1 = new Symbol1();" from my document class to my pwn class. can you point me in the correct direction please.

Comment: You can pass it as a parameter to a pawn class function, i.e. - pawn class has function getHitTest() that would be function getHitTest( mySymbol:MovieClip ), then just call pawn.getHitTest( s1 ).

Or you can set a variable in pawn class: public var symbol1:Symbol1,
and then from your other class do pawn.symbol1 = new Symbol1() or pawn.symbol1 = s1. that should do the trick.

Comment: got it ^_^ the same way I passed the stageRef. thanks for help